# Cordova, Android 10. Error with Allow List CORS

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova app for Android. With Android 10, the plugin WhiteList is deprecated.

> With the Allow List functionality now integrated into the core of Cordova Android (10.x and greater), this plugin is no longer required.

The config.xml contains:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

My remote file php contains:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

I can't find a solution. Can anybody help me? Thanks !

Comment: Are you talking about PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cordova android@10.1.0

- Make sure white list plugin is removed with command  Cordova plugin   rm       cordova-plugin-whitelist

If the above point doesnt solve the issue

- Try Adding the attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic to true in AndroidManifest.xml file inside  tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1354:
try to add the following preference at config.xml:

```
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```